# How can I constuct gulp.parallel() from an array of string?

Tags: javascript, gulp

How can I construct `gulp.parallel()` using an array of strings?

I want to be able to create function dynamically and export them as gulp tasks. The name of these functions is stored into an array named `ts`. I want to be able to create a `gulp.parallel` that would call all the dynamic function?

How can I construct `gulp.parallel()` using array of strings?

I tried the following which did not work.

```
// This will call the "mainTask" first, then call all the dynamic tasks
exports.allTasks = series(mainTask, () => gulp.parallel(ts));
```

I also tried

```
function all(cb) {
    var ts = ['task1', 'task2','task3']; // This array is generated dynamicly so I don't know the task* names until runtime.

    return gulp.parallel(...ts, (seriesDone) => {
        seriesDone();
        cb();
    });
}

exports.allTasks = series(mainTask, all);
```

But the `all` does not call the method listed in the `ts` array.

I am aware that I should be able to call `gulp.parallel('task1','task2','task3');` but not sure how to make such a call using the array.

Comment: Just to confirm: this is an array of javascript function names and not tasks created with gulp.task()?

Comment: @digby280 correct. An array of function names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

function task1(cb) {
  console.log("in task1");
  cb();
};

function task2(cb) {
  console.log("in task2");
  cb();
};

function task3(cb) {
  console.log("in task3");
  cb();
};

function mainTask(cb) {
  console.log("in mainTask");
  cb();
}

const ts = [];
ts.push(task1, task2, task3);  // or in the all function as you had it
                               // not pushing strings, but function references

function all(cb) {

  // var ts = [task1, task2, task3]; // function names aren't strings in gulp.parallel

  gulp.parallel(...ts, (seriesDone) => {

    seriesDone();
    // cb();
  })();  // () needs to be here to work

  cb();
}

exports.allTasks = gulp.series(mainTask, all);
```

Output:

```
[20:54:07] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Test Bed\taskArray\gulpfile.js
[20:54:07] Starting 'allTasks'...
[20:54:07] Starting 'mainTask'...
in mainTask
[20:54:07] Finished 'mainTask' after 3.44 ms
[20:54:07] Starting 'all'...
[20:54:07] Starting 'task1'...
[20:54:07] Starting 'task2'...
[20:54:07] Starting 'task3'...
[20:54:07] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[20:54:07] Finished 'all' after 4.23 ms
[20:54:07] Finished 'allTasks' after 15 ms
in task1
[20:54:07] Finished 'task1' after 17 ms
in task2
[20:54:07] Finished 'task2' after 19 ms
in task3
[20:54:07] Finished 'task3' after 30 ms
[20:54:07] Finished '<anonymous>' after 31 ms
```

Comment: I trick was to add the `();` at the end of the call. `})();  // () needs to be here to work` Thanks a lot!